# Write a for loop to skip every (number of elements) in an array from a starting position?

Tags: swift, for-loop

Given the below array of Int, write a for loop to skip every n elements from a starting position.

For example, if we were to skip after every 2 elements in the array below:-

```swift
let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Then the expected output would be:

> 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17

Incorrect attempt:

```
var result: [Int] = []
for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 2) {
    result.append(i)
}
print(result)
```

Comment: So you want for instance (thinking of the original sequence as a deck of cards) to deal 2, discard 2, deal 2, discard 2... Think about how you would do that in real life, then tell the computer to do it. Hint: personally I do it by going 1 2 over and over in my head.

Comment: @Wael Didn't you ask this question earlier today? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76571071/swift-a-generic-swifty-function-for-a-for-loop-that-skips-every-amount-of-numb. It's gone now, but why delete that one and create a new one?

Comment: An admin choose to close the previous question and that was the suggestion that came up and I was worried it was confusing too many people. I was getting hammered :). The question has now been answered thankfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example code. You will need to ensure the size of the array
is a multiple of the `step` size.

```
let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
var result: [Int] = []

let step = 2

for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: step) {
    if (i/step % step == 0) {
        for m in i..<i+step {
            result.append(array[m])
        }
    }
}

print("\n----> result: \(result)\n")
```

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I am after thank you so much. I just have one slight question please that I didn't want to ask earlier to avoid extra confusion. What if we also like to have an option to allow skipping the from first 2 elements from index 0 so also based on the same array above and we want to skip 2 elements but immediately from the start of the array so the output would look like: 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19?

Comment: I think I got it, I just changed this line if (i/step % step == 1) That you again and all the best to Ukraine.